# Why does one-row xts object not get a timezone? (why does it ignore/override the default argument)

Tags: r, xts

Frustrated by a unit test complaining, I narrowed it down to one `xts` object has timezone set to "UTC", the other has it set to "".

And then I've narrowed it down further to it seems to be creating an xts object with one row, compared to with 2+ rows:

```
> str(xts( c(1,2), as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00")+0:1))
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-01/2015-01-01 00:00:01 containing:
  Data: num [1:2, 1] 1 2
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL

> str(xts( c(1), as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:01")))
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-01 00:00:01/2015-01-01 00:00:01 containing:
  Data: num [1, 1] 1
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Below is the `xts` constructor. You can see the `tzone` argument gets initialized to `Sys.getenv("TZ")`, which evaluates to "UTC". So I'm confused why `tzone` would ever end up as "", based on the contents of `x`.

```
function (x = NULL, order.by = index(x), frequency = NULL, unique = TRUE, 
    tzone = Sys.getenv("TZ"), ...) 
{
    if (is.null(x) && missing(order.by)) 
        return(structure(.xts(, 0), index = integer()))
    if (!timeBased(order.by)) 
        stop("order.by requires an appropriate time-based object")
    if (inherits(order.by, "dates")) 
        tzone <- ""
    if (inherits(order.by, "Date")) {
        if (!missing(tzone)) 
            warning(paste(sQuote("tzone"), "setting ignored for Date indexes"))
        tzone <- "UTC"
    }
    if (NROW(x) > 0 && NROW(x) != length(order.by)) 
        stop("NROW(x) must match length(order.by)")
    orderBy <- class(order.by)
    if (inherits(order.by, "Date")) {
        order.by <- .POSIXct(unclass(order.by) * 86400, tz = tzone)
    }
    if (!isOrdered(order.by, strictly = !unique)) {
        indx <- order(order.by)
        if (!is.null(x)) {
            if (NCOL(x) > 1 || is.matrix(x) || is.data.frame(x)) {
                x <- x[indx, , drop = FALSE]
            }
            else x <- x[indx]
        }
        order.by <- order.by[indx]
    }
    if (!is.null(x) || length(x) != 0) {
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    }
    else x <- numeric(0)
    if (orderBy == "timeDate" && missing(tzone)) {
        tzone <- order.by@FinCenter
    }
    else if (!is.null(attr(order.by, "tzone")) && missing(tzone)) 
        tzone <- attr(order.by, "tzone")
    if (inherits(order.by, "dates")) 
        index <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(order.by), 
            "(%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S)")))
    else index <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(order.by))
    x <- structure(.Data = x, index = structure(index, tzone = tzone, 
        tclass = orderBy), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = orderBy, 
        tclass = orderBy, .indexTZ = tzone, tzone = tzone, ...)
    if (!is.null(attributes(x)$dimnames[[1]])) 
        dimnames(x) <- dimnames(x)
    x
}
```

Comment: What's your `sessionInfo()`, and `Sys.timezone()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with POSIXct objects losing their `tzone` attribute when you add an integer sequence to them. If you create the POSIXct vector using `seq`, the `tzone` attribute will be retained. To illustrate:

```
> attributes(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"))
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$tzone
[1] ""

> attributes(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01")+0)
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

> attributes(seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"), by="sec", length.out=1))
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$tzone
[1] ""
```

I need to think a bit more about whether or not this is a bug in the constructor.

---

I don't think this is a bug in the xts constructor. The issue is that the constructor honors the `tzone` attribute if it's present, and sets it to `Sys.getenv("TZ")` by default if it is not. Adding an integer sequence to a POSIXct object removes the `tzone` attribute, so that's why you see the behavior you do.

If you want a specific timezone on your index and you're creating it via `as.POSIXct`, you need to set the `tz` argument explicitly. For example:

```
> str(xts(1, as.POSIXct("2015-01-01", tz=Sys.getenv("TZ"))))
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-01/2015-01-01 containing:
  Data: num [1, 1] 1
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:01")+0` was the easiest way to fix it in my unit tests. 
I agree this is not a bug in xts constructor. It does seem, to me, to be a bug in the POSIXct add-integer code, though: dropping your timezone when an addition is done is unexpected.  (Also, POSIXct defaulting tzone to "" instead of Sys.getenv("TZ"), when not specified, is surprising behaviour; but I guess it is far too established to get it changed now.)